# 40 Device Home and Home Office Network

Tags: router, home-networking

For the most part I have around 40 devices connected via 4 unmanaged netgear switches and a prosafe router that is getting up there in age.  In addition I have 2 WAPs (multi-story home), 1 newer and a Netgear Rangemax that is about 10 years old now and I am considering replacing.

I transfer files often for work; they're either small enough to email or I use a VPN. I don't like the transfers, but the time is manageable. All of the VPNs are on the clients' side.

In addition to the work stuff I have many video streamers for services like Netflix and local media (ie Roku, Fire TV, AppleTV...), I have 8 WeMo outlets, 2 wireless thermostats, and 3 security cameras, as well as tablets and smart phones.

I am currently reorganizing my network - I have added a new Windows Server that I kind of hate and consolidating some older NAS devices into either new equipment or the server that I just mentioned.

I am beginning to see small lagging problems due to the recent addition of the thermostats and security cameras. I see a lot of traffic between devices that do not need to communicate. All of the video streamers and cameras seem okay, but the thermostats are constantly busy. The packets are small, but they're still cluttering my network.

Now for the questions:

My router is pretty old - 8 years. Should I replace it for better performance and security?
Router is about 8 years old.  It has always been solid as a rock but do I need to replace for better performance and security? Also, should I use the Rangemax until it dies? I don't have many N devices, and it has a great WAP. Also, if I upgrade my hardware, is there any benefit from using smart switches or VLANs to improve security?

Lastly, I have always been a big fan of Netgear simply because the stuff just works.  I have lamented many Linksys purchases but should my loyalty to Netgear remain?  The new Prosafe WAP has certainly not disappointed.

Comment: No need for smart switches or VLANS. If your customer's files are important enough for that, you shouldn't be transferring them over email. Newer IP cameras love to hog bandwidth - think, the nicer ones are continually transferring HD movies over your network to a storage device (if you have one). A model number of our router would be helpful.

Comment: The files I receive via email are important but they do not contain actionable information.  You could mine my email for a year and probably learn something that you could have just called and asked them.  The files I get over VPNs and my personal files are a greater concern.  I don't have active video capturing. The router is old enough that it is no longer supported but it still passes a monthly security scan.

Comment: I would just get a new router to start with, they're relatively cheap now.